# Repalce IP address in Apache Log

Tags: apache, perl, logging

I have apache logs that are generated in this format:

```
192.168.1.125 - - [25/May/2014:03:43:10 +0000] "POST /myapp/getrequest?ip=88.125.88.88 HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "11.0"
```

I wish to swap the first IP in all files with the second i.e. swap 192.168.1.125 with 88.125.88.88. The line should look like this:

```
88.125.88.88 - - [25/May/2014:03:43:10 +0000] "POST /myapp/getrequest?ip=192.168.1.125 HTTP/1.1" 200 22 "-" "11.0"
```

Reason being: I want to use a Awstats to get the Geolocation for the IP address in the first column. The way I get it now, I only get the IP address of my proxy server. The customer's IP is only in part of the request URL.

My system is a Linux machine. I am not good with Perl or sed, but googling, I came as close to:

```
perl -pe 's/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b -/xxxxxxxxxxx -/' access_log
```

I am not sure what to put for xxxxxxxxxxx. Any ideas as to how I can get this done?

Comment: You should state that you want to **swap** the IPs and not _replace_ the first one with the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -pe's/^(\S+)(\s.*?[?&]ip=)([\d.]*)/$3$2$1/' access_log
```

Non-swapping version:

```
perl -pe's/^\S+(\s.*?[?&]ip=([\d.]*))/$2$1/' access_log
```

Usage:

```
perl -pe'...' access_log > fixed_access_log
perl -i~ -pe'...' access_log                 # Edit "in-place" with backup
perl -i -pe'...' access_log                  # Edit "in-place" without backup
```

Comment: you still have an extra parentheses

Comment: I made the assumption that the IP field is populated by the proxy and thus "safe". If it isn't, you'll need to do a *lot* more work.

Comment: Thats a nice example of captured group usage.

Comment: This works perfect! But got a perl-noob Q: I see the output to screen, but the changes aren't applied to the file. What do I need to do to apply the changes to the file?

Also, if I need to leave the /myapp/getrequest?ip=192.168.1.125 part as is, i.e. not do the swap, what would the change need to be? i.e. the First IP is replaced (not swapped) with the second and the second stays the same?

Comment: @Dan `perl -i -pe ...`

Comment: @Dan change replacement part into `/$3$2$3/`

Comment: Sweet! That's it! The internet is beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -wlne '$_ =~ s/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(.*?)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/$3$2$1/; print $_' logfile
```

Comment: How is this different from the one above? Works too! Just a different regex?

Comment: Yeah, more explicit about matching an IP address, but should not matter on a log file.